# How can I write a for loop with parameters that change based on previous code?

Tags: python, html, mysql, for-loop

I have python code that retrieves some information from a mysql database. A for loop grabs each row of the database table and displays it in html. The user should be able to select what columns of the table to display through an html form, which means my for loop needs to be able to change based on the user input.

Here's my code. The last for loop is the for loop in question. Thanks for the help!

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
import mysql.connector
#CONNECTING TO THE MySQL SERVER
cnx=mysql.connector.connect(host='instruct.coe.neu.edu', user='3425cgrose', password='maceepy', database='3425cgrose')
cursor=cnx.cursor()

displayValues = form.getlist("trip")
n = len(displayValues)

if n==0:
    req.write("You have not selected any attributes")
else:
    for i in range(0,n):
        if i==0:
            attributes = displayValues[i]
        else:
            attributes = attributes + ", " + displayValues[i]

#Get trip records
query="SELECT " + attributes + " FROM TRIP;"
cursor.execute(query)

#Output results to Web page
req.write("<table border='2'>")
req.write("<tr>")
if 'TRIP_ID' in displayValues:
    req.write("<th>Trip ID</th>")
if 'CUS_ID' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Customer ID</th>")
if 'ASSET_ID' in displayValues:
    req.write("<th>Asset ID</th>")
if 'TRIP_DIST' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Trip Distance</th>")
if 'TRIP_DATE' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Trip Date</th>")
if 'TRIP_SUBTOTAL' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Trip Subtotal</th>")
if 'TRIP_TAX' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Trip Tax</th>")
if 'TRIP_TOTAL' in displayValues:    
    req.write("<th>Trip Total</th>")
req.write("</tr>")

for ("""displayValues should go here""") in cursor:
        req.write("<tr>")
        if 'TRIP_ID' in displayValues:
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_ID))
        if 'CUS_ID' in displayValues:
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(CUS_ID))
        if 'ASSET_ID' in displayValues:      
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(ASSET_ID))
        if 'TRIP_DIST' in displayValues:    
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_DIST))
        if 'TRIP_DATE' in displayValues:      
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_DATE))
        if 'TRIP_SUBTOTAL' in displayValues:     
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_SUBTOTAL))
        if 'TRIP_TAX' in displayValues:      
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_TAX))
        if 'TRIP_TOTAL' in displayValues: 
            req.write("<td> {} </td>".format(TRIP_TOTAL))
        req.write("</tr>")"     

req.write("</table>")

cursor.close
cnx.close
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a bit of JavaScript to determine what information is displayed- just like with a datagrid?